# property substitution in deployment descriptors

Tags: open-liberty

Wildfly replaces variables in deployment descriptors with System Properties

```
<activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
<activation-config-property-value>${Queue}</activation-config-property-value>
```

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/160093

Has Open Liberty a similar feature for deployment descriptors (web.xml, ejb-jar.xml)?